# how to get only the <title> with requests module

Tags: python, html

I have a lot of web pages that I just want the title from it, but requests module load the entire HTML and that seems to take a while 
how to get only the title

Comment: This isn't a trivial thing, if it's possible at all (depending on what exactly you mean). Is it really a problem to download the whole page?

Comment: You could read back the web page one byte at a time until you find `<title>` and stop when you find `</title>`. The correct way to find this is writing a SAX parser, though custom string parsing, regular expressions, or full DOM, would work too, just less efficiently. If this is a huge page, it might be beneficial. The title of a page isn't available in the http header, so that's why `requests` will never have a fancier solution for this.

Comment: You can ask the server to return a [range of bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving), but its hard to predict how many bytes you need to read to get the `<title>`. And servers aren't obliged to support byte ranges.

Answer (score -1):

You can use BeautifulSoup:
title = Tag(BeautifulSoup(html), name='title')

and to get the text from title i think you can use .get_text()

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: And how not to download the entire page?